# Json to Java using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to convert (using jackson) a json file similar to `[{"age":20,","name":"Bob"},{"age":35,","name":"Tom"}]`. Assume I have a User class (a pojo with name and age as variables - with setters and getters). Can I create `ArrayList` of User objects? Pls give me a code sample.

Comment: Please try a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayList<User> users = mapper.readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, User.class));
```